# check if product id already exists in localstorage

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage

guys i have a shopping cart in angular
my code saves the added products in localstorage, I would like my code to be able to access the 'cart' and see if the item already exists in localstorage by id

I tried this code, but without success, I would like ideas, who can help me

```
const retrieverObject: string = localStorage.getItem('cart') || '';
const retrieveObject: Array<any> = retrieverObject ? JSON.parse(retrieverObject) : [];
console.log(retrieveObject)
let presentItem = retrieveObject.find(iteml => iteml.id === item.id);

if (presentItem) {
  console.log('id already exists in localstorage')
} else {
  console.log('id not in localstorage')
}
```

I think the problem is that I can't access the cart item array

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take the elements inside the node `item` inside the `localStorage`. I could see that your `localStorage` holds your items inside the key `item`

**Pseudo Code**

```
const retrieverObject: string = localStorage.getItem('cart') || '';
const retrieveObject: Array<any> = retrieverObject ? JSON.parse(retrieverObject)?.item : [];
console.log(retrieveObject)
let presentItem = retrieveObject.find(iteml => iteml.id === item.id);

if (presentItem) {
  console.log('id already exists in localstorage')
} else {
  console.log('id not in localstorage')
}
```

Comment: I tried this code, but it returns the error 'Property 'item' does not exist on type 'any[]'.'

Comment: @LeonardoLima You tried out my latest updated code?

Comment: thanks friend, you helped me a lot, I was beating myself to do this, I hope one day I can return this favor

Answer (score 1):

in `retrieveObject`
items exists in `item` property

```
let presentItem = retrieveObject.item.find(iteml => iteml.id === item.id);
```

Comment: I tried this code, but it returns the error 'Property 'item' does not exist on type 'any[]'.' –